# nvidia problems on Ubuntu 20.04, kernel 5.8.0-36

Tags: drivers, nvidia

A couple of weeks ago I was unable to boot my laptop after a kernel update to 5.8.0-36. This was fixed by installing nvidia-driver-460. Subsequent issue with wireless and brightness controls were fixed by installing linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-36-generic. The external monitor was not recognised (and still isn't).

Yesterday (after a re-boot) I acquired the following problems:

1. The system does not wake up after suspending (has to be powered down)
2. The screen brigtness controls have gone again
3. I can't log in after a normal boot (password is not recognised?), I can login if I boot into recovery mode and then resume.

Dmesg gives

```
No Local Variables are initialized for Method [BRT6]
[13759.646843] Initialized Arguments for Method [BRT6]:  (2 arguments defined for method invocation)
[13759.646845]   Arg0:   00000000467138d9 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000001
[13759.646855]   Arg1:   00000000edd7eed7 <Obj>           Integer 0000000000000000
[13759.646870] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.BRT6 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[13759.647376] ACPI Error: Aborting method \EV5 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[13759.647785] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SMEE due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[13759.648265] ACPI Error: Aborting method \SMIE due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[13759.648584] ACPI Error: Aborting method \NEVT due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[13759.648852] ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCI0.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_NOT_FOUND) (20200528/psparse-529)
[13759.822652] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol [\_SB.PCI0.PEG0.PEGP.BRT6.LCD], AE_NOT_FOUND (20200528/psargs-330)
```

many times...

sudo apt list --installed | grep nvidia gives

```
libnvidia-cfg1-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-common-450/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 450.102.04-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed,auto-removable]
libnvidia-common-460/focal-updates,focal-updates,focal-security,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 all [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-compute-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-decode-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-encode-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-extra-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-fbc1-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-gl-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
libnvidia-ifr1-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 i386 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.8.0-34-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.8.0-34.37~20.04.2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
linux-modules-nvidia-450-5.8.0-36-generic/focal-updates,focal-security,now 5.8.0-36.40~20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-compute-utils-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-dkms-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-driver-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed]
nvidia-kernel-common-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-kernel-source-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-prime/focal,focal,now 0.8.14 all [installed,automatic]
nvidia-settings/focal-updates,now 440.82-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
nvidia-utils-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-460/focal-updates,focal-security,now 460.32.03-0ubuntu0.20.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
```

sudo ubuntu-drivers devices gives:

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001FB9sv00001028sd00000926bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : TU117GLM [Quadro T1000 Mobile]
driver   : nvidia-driver-450 - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-450-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-418-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-440-server - distro non-free
driver   : nvidia-driver-460 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to all of these was:

```
sudo dpkg -P $(dpkg -l | grep nvidia-driver | awk '{print $2}')
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-nouveau
```

The open source drivers seem a little slower but at least I can log in and the screen is bright!